# What coordinates does a line between two coordinates intersect?

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have a simple coordinate system like the following:

[image]

In this example, I have a line between two coordinates $(2,7)$ and $(8,5)$. The line is drawn from and to the exact center of each coordinate.

I'd like to calculate what coordinates are intersected by this line. Formulated differently: I need to know which coordinates the line touches.

Using the above coordinate system, a correct result would be:

$(2,7)\rightarrow(3,7)\rightarrow(4,6)\rightarrow(5,6)\rightarrow(6,6)\rightarrow(7,5) \rightarrow(8,5)$

The selected coordinates are just random, I'd like to be able to do the calculation no matter what two coordinates are selected.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would start by calculating $k$ and $n$ in the equation $y=kx+n$ so you have an exact description of the line you are working with...

Comment: Look up Bresenham's algorithm. Decades ago, when computers were slow, division and floating point operations were expensive, every line drawing function used it.

Comment: @nikie: You should add that as the answer! I'll be using this function in software and found a code implementation of Bresenham's algorithm. Just tested it and it gives the correct output. Now I just need to try and understand it :-)